# I can't select a specific item from the select option jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello friends I have an error when selecting a select option first load the combo data with this 
function 
         
[image]

content data:

the data is the same: 
code      description 
ATSG      ATSG 
CHAVEZ    CHAVEZ 
ECOSEM    ECOSEM 
LOGI      LOGI 
TEST      TEST 
WISETRACK WISETRACK

fn_grouptype(data.grouptypeId);

**once loaded I try to select with the id that the ajax returns:**

$("#dlGrupoTransporte").val(data.Transportista);

To select the item but it does not, the values ​​that the combo has are:

```
    <select id="dlGrupoTransporte" class="form-control"> 
      <option value="">SELECT</option> 
      <option value="ATSG">ATSG</option> 
      <option value="CHAVEZ">CHAVEZ</option> 
      <option value="ECOSEM">ECOSEM </option> 
      <option value="LOGI">LOGI</option> 
      <option value="TEST">TEST</option> 
      <option value="WISETRACK">WISETRACK</option> 
      <option value="WISETRACK2">WISETRACK2</option> 
      <option value="ZETRAMSA">ZETRAMSA</option> 
    </select>
```

please your help thanks.

Comment: what is data ? can u put your data example?

Comment: the data is the same:

<select id = "dlGrupoTransporte" class = "form-control">
      <option value = ""> SELECT </option>
      <option value = "ATSG"> ATSG </option>
      <option value = "CHAVEZ"> CHAVEZ </option>
      <option value = "ECOSEM"> ECOSEM </option>
      <option value = "LOGI"> LOGI </option>
      <option value = "TEST"> TEST </option>
      <option value = "WISETRACK"> WISETRACK </option>
      <option value = "WISETRACK2"> WISETRACK2 </option>
      <option value = "ZETRAMSA"> ZETRAMSA </option>                            
 </select>

Comment: the data is the same:

code                 description
ATSG                ATSG
CHAVEZ           CHAVEZ
ECOSEM          ECOSEM
LOGI                 LOGI
TEST                TEST
WISETRACK    WISETRACK
WISETRACK2  WISETRACK2
ZETRAMSA      ZETRAMSA

Comment: I would double check that data.Transportista matches one of the options. Or just hardcode `$("#dlGrupoTransporte").val('ATSG');` to see if this part of your code works first. If the jQuery works, something is wrong with your data. If the jQuery doesn't work, look into why not.

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional code, in a code block

Comment: but in other select option if it works for me alone in this it fails me

Comment: So then you know your jQuery code is correct, but maybe then `data` has some error in it? One of those has to be wrong else your code would work :)